# How to get updated entities from JPA resultList .?

Tags: java, jpa

I have updated an object within the transaction, its successfully updated and sync up with database...but whenever I'm retrieving the entities using query.getResultList() , its not returning the List with updated Objects and values.

Here is code refers How i'm doing...

```
    javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Siddhant-PC:1521:XEPU").createEntityManager(); 
    javax.persistence.Query professionalWorkQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProfessionalWork p order by p.jobNo");
    java.util.List<ProfessionalWork> professionalWorkList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : professionalWorkQuery.getResultList();
```

Code for updating an Object...

```
ProfessionalWork proWork = entityManager.find(ProfessionalWork.class, jobNo);

                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                    proWork.setStatus("Ready");
                    proWork.setReadyTime(DateWrapper.getTime());
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Code for retrieving all objects...

```
professionalWorkList = professionalWorkQuery.getResultList();
    Iterator lab =  professionalWorkList.listIterator();
    while(lab.hasNext()){
           ProfessionalWork pWork = (ProfessionalWork) lab.next();
           System.out.println(pWork.getJobNo()+" -- "+pWork.getStatus()); 
              //Here i'm getting All Objects(even newly added objects also...but i'm not getting my modified values in objects)
     }
professionalWorkList.clear();
```

Comment: Can you try this once , professionalWorkQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");

Comment: Thanks brother...It worked for me...:)

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just referenced the document here : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html. Glad it worked !

professionalWorkQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");